# sscanf: %* doesn't ignore empty fields

Tags: c, scanf, c11

Reading a line from a file, using sscanf with `%*` to ignore a unwanted field like this

```
int count = sscanf(linha,
                       "%*[^\t]\t%4[^\t]"
                       &livro->area);
```

only works when the field has characters
`"20/out/17\tINF\t"`
but it doesn't work when the field to be ignored is empty `"\tINF\t"`

Can someone explain to me why that is and how I can make it also ignore it if empty?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [description](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12) of the `%[...]` specifier (emphasis added):

> Matches a **nonempty** sequence of characters from a set of expected characters (the scanset).

So it will never match an empty string.

Maybe you should be using `strtok()` rather than `sscanf()`.

Comment: thanks! is there any way to match (and ignore) empty and not empty fields?

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use `sscanf()` to do what `strtok()` does better.

Answer (score 1):

> how I can make it also ignore it if empty?

As `sscanf(s, "%*[^\t]", ....)` does not ignore empty fields, use 2 `sscanf()` and record how far the first scanned - if at all.

```
int offset = 0;  // Use this value if the below sscanf() fails to reach %n
sscanf(linha, "%*[^\t]%n", &offset);
int count = sscanf(linha + offset, "\t%4[^\t]", &livro->area);
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if more than one field needs to be ignored (as is the case in the real code I need this for)

Comment: @Tiago That is a new goal not posted in the question.  IAC, better to consider a new approach and parse the tabs within the line with `strspn(), strcspn()`.